# PySpark: Fill NAs with mode of column based on aggregation of other columns

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, conditional-statements, pyspark

** Please note the edits at the bottom, with an adapted solution script from Anna K. (thank you!) **

I have a dataframe with 4 columns:

```
# Compute the mode to fill NAs for Item
values = [(None, 'Red', 3, 10), (None, 'Red', 6, 20), ('A', 'Green', 5, 30),
         ('A', 'Red', 3, 10), (None, 'Green', 6, 10), ('B', 'Green', 5, 10),
         ('B', 'Orange', 6, 20), ('A', 'Red', 3, 20), ('B', 'Green', 5, 30),
         (None, 'Red', 3, 10)]
items = spark.createDataFrame(values, ['Item', 'Color', 'Weight', 'Price'])
items.show()

#+----+------+------+-----+
#|Item| Color|Weight|Price|
#+----+------+------+-----+
#|null|   Red|     3|   10|
#|null|   Red|     6|   20|
#|   A| Green|     5|   30|
#|   A|   Red|     3|   10|
#|null| Green|     6|   10|
#|   B| Green|     5|   10|
#|   B|Orange|     6|   20|
#|   A|   Red|     3|   20|
#|   B| Green|     5|   30|
#|null|   Red|     3|   10|
#+----+------+------+-----+
```

I would like to fill the null 'Item' values with the mode of the 'Item' column when grouped by 'Weight' and 'Color':

```
grouped = items.where(items['Item'].isNotNull()).groupBy('Item', 'Weight', 'Color').count()
window = Window.partitionBy('Weight').orderBy(desc("count"))
grouped = grouped\
    .withColumn('order', row_number().over(window))\
    .where(col('order') == 1)

grouped.show()

#+----+------+------+-----+-----+
#|Item|Weight| Color|count|order|
#+----+------+------+-----+-----+
#|   B|     6|Orange|    1|    1|
#|   B|     5| Green|    2|    1|
#|   A|     3|   Red|    2|    1|
#+----+------+------+-----+-----+
```

In this case, all null 'Item' values with a 'Weight' and 'Color' combination of 6 and Orange will be assigned 'B'.

All null 'Item' values with a 'Weight' = 5 and 'Color' = Green will also be assigned 'B'.

Null 'Item' records with 'Weight' = 3 and 'Color' = Red will be assigned Item = A.

My first thought was to perform some sort of join using this new grouped df and my original df- but it's failing, and is also massively inelegant. Is there a more streamlined way to do this?

```
# Not elegant, and not working...

# Add new empty column to fill NAs
items = items.withColumn('item_weight_impute', lit(None))

# Select columns to include in the join based on weight
items.join(grouped.select('Item','Weight','Color'), ['Item','Weight','Color'], 'left_outer') \
    .withColumn('item_weight_impute', when((col('Item').isNull()), grouped.Item).otherwise(items.Item)) \
    .select('Item','Color','Weight', 'Price','item_weight_impute') \
    .show()

#+----+------+------+-----+------------------+
#|Item| Color|Weight|Price|item_weight_impute|
#+----+------+------+-----+------------------+
#|   B|Orange|     6|   20|                 B|
#|   A| Green|     5|   30|                 A|
#|null|   Red|     3|   10|              null|
#|null|   Red|     3|   10|              null|
#|   B| Green|     5|   30|                 B|
#|   B| Green|     5|   10|                 B|
#|null| Green|     6|   10|              null|
#|   A|   Red|     3|   20|                 A|
#|   A|   Red|     3|   10|                 A|
#|null|   Red|     6|   20|              null|
#+----+------+------+-----+------------------+
```

**EDITS! Courtesy of Anna K.**
Here is an adaptation of the answer with a twist- perhaps we would like to programmatically impute > 1 categorical column. Here, we impute Item and Color based on the combination of Weight and Price:

```
# Practice- compute hierarchical modes to fill NAs for Item and Color
values = [(None, 'Red', 3, 10), (None, 'Red', 6, 20), ('A', 'Green', 5, 30),
         ('A', None, 3, 10), (None, None, 6, 10), ('B', 'Green', 5, 10),
         ('B', 'Orange', 6, 20), ('A', 'Red', 3, 20), ('B', None, 5, 30),
         (None, 'Red', 3, 10)]
items = spark.createDataFrame(values, ['Item', 'Color', 'Weight', 'Price'])
items.show()
#+----+------+------+-----+
#|Item| Color|Weight|Price|
#+----+------+------+-----+
#|null|   Red|     3|   10|
#|null|   Red|     6|   20|
#|   A| Green|     5|   30|
#|   A|  null|     3|   10|
#|null|  null|     6|   10|
#|   B| Green|     5|   10|
#|   B|Orange|     6|   20|
#|   A|   Red|     3|   20|
#|   B|  null|     5|   30|
#|null|   Red|     3|   10|
#+----+------+------+-----+

mode_columns=['Item', 'Color']

# Weight + Price
for item in mode_columns:
    # Count all occurrences of Weight + Price combos
    df1 = (items
       .dropna(subset=[f'{item}'])
       .groupBy(f'{item}', "Weight", "Price")
       .agg(f.count("Price").alias("count")))

    # Reduce df1 to only include those most frequent Weight + Price combos
    df2 = (df1
       .groupBy("Weight", "Price")
       .agg(f.max("count").alias("count")))

    # Join with df of counts to get the {item} mode
    grouped = (df1
           .join(df2, ["Weight", "Price", "count"])
           .withColumnRenamed(f'{item}', f'{item}_fill_value')
           .drop("count"))
    
    #Join with original df
    items = items.join(grouped, ["Weight", "Price"], "left" )
    
    # Coalesce the original and imputed {item} columns
    items = items.withColumn(f'{item}_weight_price_impute', f.coalesce(f'{item}', f'{item}_fill_value'))
    items = items.drop(f'{item}', f'{item}_fill_value')
    items = items.withColumnRenamed(f'{item}_weight_price_impute', f'{item}')
    items.show()
#+------+-----+----+------+
#|Weight|Price|Item| Color|
#+------+-----+----+------+
#|     5|   30|   B| Green|
#|     5|   30|   B| Green|
#|     5|   30|   A| Green|
#|     5|   30|   A| Green|
#|     3|   20|   A|   Red|
#|     6|   10|null|  null|
#|     5|   10|   B| Green|
#|     3|   10|   A|   Red|
#|     3|   10|   A|   Red|
#|     3|   10|   A|   Red|
#|     6|   20|   B|   Red|
#|     6|   20|   B|   Red|
#|     6|   20|   B|Orange|
#|     6|   20|   B|Orange|
#+------+-----+----+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have *grouped*, you can do a left join of *items* with *grouped*, and then use coalesce to fill in null values in Item column. Coalesce function returns the first column that is not null.

Step 1. get grouped df:

```
df1 = (items
   .dropna()
   .groupBy("Item", "Weight", "Color")
   .agg(F.count("Price").alias("count")))

df2 = (df1
   .groupBy("Weight", "Color")
   .agg(F.max("count").alias("count")))

grouped = (df1
       .join(df2, ["Weight", "Color", "count"])
       .withColumnRenamed("Item", "fill_value")
       .drop("count"))
```

Step 2. Left join items with grouped

```
df = items.join(grouped, ["Weight", "Color"], "left" )
```

Step 3. apply coalesce

```
df_filled = df.withColumn("item_weight_impute", F.coalesce("Item", "fill_value"))
```

df_filled is now

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you Anna! The step-by-step was clear and the code is really clean. I'm going to edit the original question above to include a method of programmatically imputing multiple categorical variables with an adaptation of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the join (left / right as you like ) , Here is a proposition and I hope that I will help :

```
!pwd
!export SPARK_HOME="/usr/spark-2.4.4/python/pyspark/"

import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession 
spark =  SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
     .appName("null-fill") \
 .getOrCreate()
   
values = [(None, 'Red', 3, 10), (None, 'Red', 6, 20), ('A', 'Green', 5, 30),
         ('A', 'Red', 3, 10), (None, 'Green', 6, 10), ('B', 'Green', 5, 10),
         ('B', 'Orange', 6, 20), ('A', 'Red', 3, 20), ('B', 'Green', 5, 30),
         (None, 'Red', 3, 10)]
items = spark.createDataFrame(values, ['Item', 'Color', 'Weight', 'Price'])
items.show()
```

```
/usr/spark-2.4.4/work_dir/notebooks
+----+------+------+-----+
|Item| Color|Weight|Price|
+----+------+------+-----+
|null|   Red|     3|   10|
|null|   Red|     6|   20|
|   A| Green|     5|   30|
|   A|   Red|     3|   10|
|null| Green|     6|   10|
|   B| Green|     5|   10|
|   B|Orange|     6|   20|
|   A|   Red|     3|   20|
|   B| Green|     5|   30|
|null|   Red|     3|   10|
+----+------+------+-----+
```

```
from  pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
grouped = items.where(items['Item'].isNotNull()).groupBy('Item', 'Weight', 'Color').count()
window = Window.partitionBy('Weight').orderBy(desc("count"))
grouped = grouped\
    .withColumn('order', row_number().over(window))\
    .where(col('order') == 1)

grouped.show()
```

```
|Item|Weight| Color|count|order|
+----+------+------+-----+-----+
|   B|     6|Orange|    1|    1|
|   B|     5| Green|    2|    1|
|   A|     3|   Red|    2|    1|
+----+------+------+-----+-----+
```

Then we apply the join based on the condition "weight":

```
left_join = grouped.alias('tr').join(items, (grouped.Weight == items.Weight),how='left')
df_edited = left_join.select("tr.Item","tr.Weight","tr.Color","tr.count","tr.order","Price") 
df_edited.show()
```

```
+----+------+------+-----+-----+-----+
|Item|Weight| Color|count|order|Price|
+----+------+------+-----+-----+-----+
|   B|     6|Orange|    1|    1|   20|
|   B|     6|Orange|    1|    1|   10|
|   B|     6|Orange|    1|    1|   20|
|   B|     5| Green|    2|    1|   30|
|   B|     5| Green|    2|    1|   10|
|   B|     5| Green|    2|    1|   30|
|   A|     3|   Red|    2|    1|   10|
|   A|     3|   Red|    2|    1|   10|
|   A|     3|   Red|    2|    1|   20|
|   A|     3|   Red|    2|    1|   10|
+----+------+------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost good at what you've tried.  Here is a working one (fixed the last step of the join):

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


w = Window.partitionBy('Weight', 'Color')

grouped = items.filter("Item is not null") \
    .withColumn('count', F.count("*").over(w)) \
    .withColumn('rn', F.row_number().over(w.orderBy(F.desc("count")))) \
    .where("rn = 1") \
    .select('Item', 'Weight', 'Color')

items.alias("item").join(grouped.alias("mode"), ['Weight', 'Color'], "left") \
    .select("item.*", F.coalesce("item.Item", "mode.Item").alias("item_weight_impute")) \
    .show()

#+------+------+----+-----+------------------+
#|Weight| Color|Item|Price|item_weight_impute|
#+------+------+----+-----+------------------+
#|     6|Orange|   B|   20|                 B|
#|     3|   Red|null|   10|                 A|
#|     3|   Red|   A|   10|                 A|
#|     3|   Red|   A|   20|                 A|
#|     3|   Red|null|   10|                 A|
#|     6| Green|null|   10|              null|
#|     5| Green|   A|   30|                 A|
#|     5| Green|   B|   10|                 B|
#|     5| Green|   B|   30|                 B|
#|     6|   Red|null|   20|              null|
#+------+------+----+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: My solution is almost the same. I think to get the mode correctly in grouped, we need to partition Window by both Weight and Color, not just Weight. Or am I missing something?

Comment: ^ Yes, this answer is a good one for partitioning at a different level, though!